# Histogram3D with imported data

Tags: plotting, import, histograms, charts

It's been a while since I used Mathematica. Today I tried to visualize some data that I have in a text file. There are two columns, the first with integer values between 10 and 50 and the 2nd with floating point values around 0.005. The file has 100000 lines. The values are not sorted in any way.

I loaded the data with `data1=Import["data_file", "Table"]`, and the truncated display seems to contain the right values.

Then I tried simply Histogram3d[data1], but all I get is an empty wireframe with both axes scaled 0 to 1. I also tried ListLinePlot and also simply got an empty wireframe.

I tried just reading the first 100 lines, but got the same results.

This is with Mathematica 11.0.0 on Linux.

Comment: try this `Mean /@ data1`. You should expect a pair of numbers like `{30,0.005}`  In case you have some non-numeric junk in the file you will see.

Comment: Mean /@ data1 gives me a large list of values

Comment: If your file is actually $100,000x2$ then `Mean/@data1` should indeed produce a single list with $100,000$ entries; perhaps doing something like `Mean/@data1//Dimensions` might tell you what are the dimensions of the list;

Comment: oops sorry should have been `Mean/@Transpose[data1]` , but I see you fixed it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. I was using "Table" with `Import`. I changed that to "CSV" and it worked.